# DVB-T tuner works on openelec and windows but not on ubuntu

Tags: dvb-t

I have Geniatech/Mygica T230 tv tuner, when scanning on kodibuntu (kernel version 3.19) the scan failed with no channels found (I used w_scan).

I also tried on my laptop (dual boot windows and ubuntu 16.04), it works on windows but not on ubuntu.

I also works on openelec v6.95.

Any direction on how to fix this?
Let me know if you need more information.

I thought maybe to copy the firmware of openelec to ubuntu, but I don't know how to do it or if it will work.

[1] https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Geniatech_T230

[2] https://github.com/OpenELEC/dvb-firmware

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by copy the following files from openelec firmware to /lib/firmware

https://github.com/OpenELEC/dvb-firmware/blob/master/firmware/dvb-tuner-si2158-a20-01.fw

https://github.com/OpenELEC/dvb-firmware/blob/master/firmware/dvb-demod-si2168-b40-01.fw